# SQL error ORA 01427 - Subquery returns more than 1 row resulted from update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ora-01427

Anyone can help me correct this SQL query below? I got error that says subquery return more than 1 row. Thanks.

```
UPDATE LINEITEM a
SET a.l_manufacturer_name=(with NAMES as (SELECT CASE
    WHEN MOD(b.L_PARTKEY,2)=0 THEN (SELECT M_NAME FROM MANUFACTURER m WHERE ROWNUM=1)
    WHEN MOD(b.L_PARTKEY,2)=1 THEN (SELECT M_NAME FROM (SELECT M_NAME, ROWNUM AS MYROW FROM (SELECT M_NAME, ROWNUM FROM MANUFACTURER m)) WHERE MYROW=2)
END AS MANUFACTURER_NAME FROM LINEITEM b)
SELECT MANUFACTURER_NAME FROM NAMES N WHERE N.L_PARTKEY=A.L_PARTKEY;
```

Comment: The main question is: what are you trying to achieve? With `rownum` you select arbitrarily picked rows. (E.g. you tell the DBMS: select the record from the `manufacturer` table that you happen to read first, which can be any record from the table.) You select such random `manufacturer` record for each `lineitem` record. Then from all these random records you try to pick exactly one with a matching `l_partkey` (which you haven't even selected). I suggest you open another request telling us what you are trying to do (with sample data and expected result).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error message is obvious(*Too_Many_Rows exception raised due to the returning results for at least one select statement has more than one row* ). In such cases an aggregate function may help us depending on our situation :

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURER(M_NAME varchar2(75));
SQL> CREATE TABLE LINEITEM(l_manufacturer_name varchar2(75),l_partkey int);

SQL> INSERT INTO MANUFACTURER VALUES('abc');
SQL> INSERT INTO MANUFACTURER VALUES('def');
SQL> INSERT INTO LINEITEM VALUES('abc',1);
SQL> INSERT INTO LINEITEM VALUES('def',2);
SQL> INSERT INTO LINEITEM VALUES('abc',1);
SQL> INSERT INTO LINEITEM VALUES('def',2);

SQL> UPDATE LINEITEM a
   SET a.l_manufacturer_name =
       (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN MOD(b.L_PARTKEY, 2) = 0 THEN
                  (SELECT M_NAME FROM MANUFACTURER m WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
                 WHEN MOD(b.L_PARTKEY, 2) = 1 THEN
                  (SELECT M_NAME
                     FROM (SELECT M_NAME, ROWNUM AS MYROW
                             FROM (SELECT M_NAME, ROWNUM FROM MANUFACTURER m))
                    WHERE MYROW = 2)
               END AS MANUFACTURER_NAME
          FROM LINEITEM b
         WHERE a.l_partkey = b.l_partkey);


ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row 


SQL> UPDATE LINEITEM a
   SET a.l_manufacturer_name =
       (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN MOD(max(b.L_PARTKEY), 2) = 0 THEN
                  (SELECT M_NAME FROM MANUFACTURER m WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
                 WHEN MOD(max(b.L_PARTKEY), 2) = 1 THEN
                  (SELECT M_NAME
                     FROM (SELECT M_NAME, ROWNUM AS MYROW
                             FROM (SELECT M_NAME, ROWNUM FROM MANUFACTURER m))
                    WHERE MYROW = 2)
               END AS MANUFACTURER_NAME
          FROM LINEITEM b
         WHERE a.l_partkey = b.l_partkey
         GROUP BY b.L_PARTKEY );

4 row updated.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `ROWNUM` in the inner most query of your `MOD(b.L_PARTKEY,2)=0` case.

The way ROWNUM works, is basically that it will get assigned to a row in a result after the `WHERE` clause has been evaluated.

This means that when you are refering to `ROWNUM=1` in the `WHERE` clause, you are trying to compare it before it has been assigned.

In the other `CASE` with `MOD(b.L_PARTKEY,2)=1` you have an inner select that returns a `ROWNUM`, you then refer to it with `MYROW=2` outside that inner query. That works, because the `ROWNUM` has been assigned to each of the rows in that result by then.

You should consider doing the same for the first `CASE` as you do for the second:

```
UPDATE LINEITEM a 
  SET a.l_manufacturer_name = (
    SELECT
      CASE 
        WHEN MOD(b.L_PARTKEY,2)=0 
          THEN (
            SELECT
              M_NAME 
            FROM (
              SELECT 
                M_NAME, 
                ROWNUM AS MYROW 
              FROM (
                SELECT 
                  M_NAME, 
                  ROWNUM 
                FROM MANUFACTURER m
              )
            ) 
            WHERE 
              MYROW=1) 
        WHEN MOD(b.L_PARTKEY,2)=1 
          THEN (
            SELECT
              M_NAME 
            FROM (
              SELECT 
                M_NAME, 
                ROWNUM AS MYROW 
              FROM (
                SELECT 
                  M_NAME, 
                  ROWNUM 
                FROM MANUFACTURER m
              )
            ) 
            WHERE 
              MYROW=2) 
      END AS MANUFACTURER_NAME 
    FROM LINEITEM b 
    WHERE 
      a.l_partkey=b.l_partkey);
```

This should ensure that only one row is returned from either case, and your assignment should work.

Comment: thanks. however the query seems to load forever and unable to finish. not sure cos the database contains 1.8m or other reason. so i aborted this operation.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all. I realise my mistake. It's because there must be a primary key during the matching.